# Open Server настройка апатча и php ini

Tags: php, apache, openserver, php.ini

Есть следующая инструкция 
Заходим в папку Апача и находим там Ваш конфигурационный файл, например `httpd.conf`, открываем редактором и вносим следующую строку в блок вашего хоста:

`php_value auto_prepend_file var/www/dg.ru/www/maoli/core/config/config.home.php`

Данной строкой мы включаем конфигурационный файл который является стандартным для каждого файла в пределах данного хоста.

Как это осуществить в `OpenServer`?

Comment: Правой кнопкой по иконке в трее, там `Дополнительно`->`Конфигурация`->`Apache2.4`- это то что нужно?

Comment: Не совсем, решение уже найдено